# Exemplary code for payment

Tags: android, ios, in-app-purchase, payment, codenameone

Can someone provide me a functioning payment class? My code is below.

My problem is: My purchase method returns true before the payment has succeeded. (In other words: the pay method returns a token and then asks for login for itunes or google-play store. The user must not continue with the purchase as he/she has already the possibility to continue.

```
public boolean purchase() {

  final Purchase p = Purchase.getInAppPurchase();
  boolean retVal = true;
  if (p != null) {
     if (p.isManagedPaymentSupported()) {
        if (Display.getInstance().getPlatformName().equalsIgnoreCase(Constants.ANDROID)) {
           p.purchase(Payment.SKUS_AND[this.membershipType]);
        }
        else {
           p.purchase(Payment.SKUS_IOS[this.membershipType]);
        }
     }
     else {
        String retToken = null;
        if (p.isManualPaymentSupported()) {
           if (Display.getInstance().getPlatformName().equalsIgnoreCase(Constants.IOS)) {
              retToken = p.pay(Payment.ITEM_COSTS[this.membershipType], Payment.CURRENCY, "lfiuhlecfhbweucfbhewucfbhewluh");
           }
           else {
              retToken = p.pay(Payment.ITEM_COSTS[this.membershipType], Payment.CURRENCY, "6578346756347865783");
           }
           retVal = retToken != null;
        }
        else {
           UITools.infoDialog(Settings.getInstance().getLocalizedText(TextConstants.UNSUPPORTED_PAYMENT));
           retVal = false;
        }
     }
  }
  else {
     UITools.infoDialog(Settings.getInstance().getLocalizedText(TextConstants.UNSUPPORTED_PAYMENT));
     retVal = false;
  }
  return retVal;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Purchase is asynchronous so when you call a method like `purchase` it returns immediately without confirming or denying the success of the payment process.

Your main class must implement the `PurchaseCallback` where you will receive the appropriate callbacks when purchase succeeds/fails. Specifically `itemPurchased` should be invoked when payment is completed.